# Login por Api Token Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Estoy realizando una login por api_token usando laravel 5.4

La ruta esta definida como

```
Route::get('/test', 'Auth\authenticatedApiLogin@authenticatedApiLogin')->middleware('auth:api');
```

Y si hago dentro del método:

```
dd(Auth::guard('api')->user())
```

me muestra bien el usuario, sin embargo al querer autenticar una instancia de este usuario para el guard web realizando lo siguiente no funciona:

```
  public function authenticatedApiLogin() {

         Auth::guard('web')->login(Auth::guard('api')->user());


        return redirect()->route('venta.homes.index');

    }
```

Al hacer lo anterior, cierra sesiòn y me manda a la pantalla de login.

Si imprimo dd(Auth::guard('web')) me muestra:

```
SessionGuard {#674 ▼
  #name: "web"
  #lastAttempted: null
  #viaRemember: false
  #session: Store {#666 ▶}
  #cookie: CookieJar {#679 ▶}
  #request: Request {#40 ▶}
  #events: Dispatcher {#5 ▶}
  #loggedOut: false
  #tokenRetrievalAttempted: false
  #user: UsersModel {#681 ▶}
  #provider: EloquentUserProvider {#673 ▶}
}
```

La ruta que yo quiero ingresar tiene el middleware Auth, la primera vez que entra detecha el Guard Api, la segunda, luego de hacer Auth::guard('web')->login(Auth::guard('api')->user()) ya no me detecta el guard.

Viendo el log del siguiente método (class Authenticate) se ve lo siguiente:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards) {

    Log::info($guards);

    $this->authenticate($guards);

    return $next($request);
}
```

> [2017-04-27 12:37:07] local.INFO: array (
>     0 => 'api',
>   )
>   [2017-04-27 12:37:07] local.INFO: array (
>   )

El archivo Auth.php tiene lo siguiente:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session", "token"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => MolInterno\Users\UsersModel::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],

];
```

Comment: ¿qué es lo que muestra el primer dd()?

Comment: ahi justo edite, a que dd() te referis? que parte? @Shaz

Comment: Me refiero a esta parte: Y si hago dentro del método:

`dd(Auth::guard('api')->user())`

Comment: UsersModel {#682 ▼
  #table: "users"
  #fillable: array:4 [▶]
  #hidden: array:2 [▶]
  #dates: array:1 [▶]
  #connection: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  +timestamps: true
  #attributes: array:10 [▶]
  #original: array:10 [▶]
  #relations: []
  #visible: []
  #appends: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #dateFormat: null
  #casts: []
  #touches: []
  #observables: []
  #with: []
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #rememberTokenName: "remember_token"
  #forceDeleting: false
} @Shaz

Comment: Es raro porque si hago dd(Auth::guard('web')->user()) tambien me muestar el usuario. No estoy entiendo esto!! @Shaz

Comment: Por favor agrega la información relacionada a la pregunta y no como comentarios, es un poco díficil leer código acá. ¿puedes mostrar tu archivo auth.php de la carpeta config?

Comment: Disculpa, edito mi post en base a tu pregunta? o respondo a mi pregunta directamente para responderte? @Shaz

Comment: Abre consola y muestra como sn las routas **venta.homes.index** y **\test**
el comando para mostrar todas las rutas es:
**php artisan route:list**

Answer (score 0):

Este tutorial es muy especifico al respecto,

https://blog.flicher.net/laravel-rest-api-passport-authentication-for-ionic-app/

Algunos aspectos importantes, una vez autenticado el user, debe retornar el token de acceso, e inmediatamente guardarlo en la localstorage, generalmente lo guardo ahi, para que luego cuando recargues la pagina y hagas un llamado ajax envies el token de acceso y se pueda autenticar correctamente y obtener los datos del usuario;

Answer (score 0):

Segun veo el problema esta en :

```
 public function authenticatedApiLogin() {

     Auth::guard('web')->login(Auth::guard('api')->user());


    return redirect()->route('venta.homes.index');

}
```

prueba esto:

```
if(Auth::guard('api')->attempt(['username' => request('username'), 'password' => request('password')])){
        $user = Auth::guard('api')->user();
}
```

y como bien te dice el compañero tienes que crear un token mediante Passport https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport , para poder hacer el logout despues y poder determinar a que Routes acceden lo users que esten logueados:

```
if(! $user == null){
   $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('app')->accessToken;
   return response()->json(['succes' => $success, 'user' => $user]);
}else{
   return response()->json(['error' =>'Usuario no encontrado.'],401);
 }
```

Y en tu model User tienes que poner:

```
 use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
 class UserApp extends Authenticatable 
 {
    use HasApiTokens;

    protected $guard = 'api';
 }
```

Y en tu Auth.php:

```
  'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
```

Me costo mucho crear un nuevo guard para mi aplicacion en Laravel, pero con esto me funciono.